# Python: Read Pandas Dataframe from csv File, Make Filtered Output to Another File as csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a bunch of N csv files that I would like to read into memory, filter for certain characteristics and write via append M csv files - with the same format as the input files.

If I work with

```
df = pd.read_csv
...
for index, line in df.iterrows():
    with open(fullOutputFileName, 'a') as f:
        line.to_csv(fullOutputFileName, index.None)
```

I do not get one output line

```
attr1, attr2, attr3
```

for one input line, but something like:

```
attr1
attr2
attr3
```

(as this is probably the way how a Panda Series is written to the filesystem).

Is there any other way to perform this task (perhaps without Pandas)?

Comment: How big are your csv files? The downside of Pandas is that is has to load everything into memory, which can be bad if the csv files are enormous, but fine for smaller files.

Comment: below 200 MByte, so I am able to read them completely in the memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't attempt to write each line individually, dataframes have [`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) method.

```
df = pd.read_csv('input.csv')
# some filtering logic, for example:
filtered_df = df[df['col a'] == 2]
filtered_df.to_csv('output.csv')
```